# chart in APEX 18.1.0.00.41 shows label name as "group xx"

Tags: oracle, charts, oracle-apex

It's the first time I use APEX. Currently I have APEX 18.1.0.00.41. When I run my App, in my chart, it shows a label name as "group xx".

[image: chart with wrong label name]

Answer (score 0):

There is a new setting in 18.1 on the series. Look in the Label section, there is now "Display As", which determines what is being displayed.